# Visual Studio 2019 CS8032 An Instance of Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InternalUsageDiagnosticAnalyzer cannot be created from C:\folder

Tags: visual-studio

I was working on my VS .net core 3.1 project on another machine, It builds without errors and warning.

It is checked out on another machine and Visual Studio 2019 Professional is showing CS8032 warning

Visual Studio 2019 CS8032 An Instance of Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InternalUsageDiagnosticAnalyzer cannot be created from C:\Project\package\MicrosoftEntityFrameworkCore.analyzers\5.0.2\analyzers\dotnet\cs\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Analyzers.dll: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=3.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I checked the filepath of the dll and it is there. I tried uninstalling v5.0.2 to v5.0.1 of Microsoft.EntityFrameWorkCore.InMemory but the warning is still there.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks